# Determine whether the system has unique solution, many solutions, or has no solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Given the augmented matrix of a linear system :
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & * & * & * \\
0 & 1 & * & * \\
0 & 0 & 1 & * \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
with * are unknown real numbers. Determine whether the system has unique solution, many solutions, or has no solution.

---

Attempt :

The answer key from the textbook says it has unique solution. But, if the $* = 0$, we get  a counterexample

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Which means that $a=c_{1}, b=c_{2}, c = c_{3}$, but the $d$ is free.

Notice that in general we can do operations so that it will become

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & * \\
0 & 1 & 0 & * \\
0 & 0 & 1 & * \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

So again, whether * nonzero or not, we will have infinitely many solutions.

How is this analysis? I presume the answer key is mistaken. The textbook is *Elementary Linear Algebra applications version 11, by Howard Anton and Chris Rorres.* Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an augmented system, isn't the last column the right-hand side?  In that case, the augmented system is upper triangular, with ones on the diagonal.  What does that tell you?

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that augmented matrix is the one which includes the right-hand side.